# QT Multi-threading & Updating GUI

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I'm currently updating an existing codebase designed to be used with a GTK GUI to QT, so that it can implement multi threading, as the functions take hours to complete.

This codebase makes frequent calls to a function `display(std::string)`, for the purpose of updating a text display widget. I redefined this function for the new QT version:

In Display.cpp:

```
void display(std::string output)
{
    //
    MainWindow * gui = MainWindow::getMainWinPtr(); //Gets instance of GUI
    gui->DisplayInGUI(output); //Sends string to new QT display function
}
```

In MainWindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::DisplayInGUI(std::string output)
{
    //converts output to qstring and displays in text edit widget
}

void MainWindow::mainFunction(){
    //calls function in existing codebase, which itself is frequently calling display()
}

void MainWindow::on_mainFunctionButton_released()
{
    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::mainFunction);
}
```

If I run the main function in a new thread, `display(std::string)` won't update the GUI until the thread completes.  I understand why; the GUI can only be updated in the main thread.  Everything else functions as intended. 
What I want to implement, but I'm not sure how, is having `display(std:string)` send a signal back to the main thread to call `MainWindow::DisplayInGUI(output_text)` with the string that was passed to the display() function.  I believe this is the correct way to do it, but correct me if I'm wrong. I want to avoid changing the existing codebase at all costs.

EDIT: I should add that for some dumb reasons entirely out of my control, I am forced to use C++98 (yeah, I know)

Comment: Remember: with Qt, *all* code that updates widgets or otherwise does any graphics rendering, *must* run on the main (aka GUI) thread.

Comment: You should use signals and slots between the threads and the main thread instead of direct access of any widget in a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Many Qt major versions have not supported C++98-only compilation. So what Qt old version do you use? That's quite important and this question changes character quite a bit depending on the Qt version you're stuck on. If you use recent Qt, there's no such thing as "stuck to C++98". Qt itself uses C++11 or even C++14, and it's in all of its APIs, so it's not really feasible to somehow sidestep it without being stuck with "ancient" APIs that are retained for backwards-compatibility. Qt headers won't compile without a C++11 compiler, so you're not "stuck" unless it's old Qt.

Comment: Basically, by using any reasonably modern Qt version, you're using a C++11 compiler at the very least, so the idea of being "stuck" is somewhat illusory. I guess don't use modern C++ libraries if you can't use a modern C++ compiler? Are you using Qt 4?

Answer (score 1):

You must schedule the code that does UI calls to run in the main thread. I use a simple and easy to use wrapper for that:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <utility>

template<typename F>
void runInMainThread(F&& fun)
{
    QObject tmp;
    QObject::connect(&tmp, &QObject::destroyed, qApp, std::forward<F>(fun),
                     Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

You can now run code (using a lambda in this example, but any other callable will work) in the main thread like this:

```
runInMainThread([] { /* code */ });
```

In your case:

```
void display(std::string output)
{
    runInMainThread([output = std::move(output)] {
        MainWindow* gui = MainWindow::getMainWinPtr();
        gui->DisplayInGUI(output);
    });
}
```

Or you can leave `display()` as is and instead wrap the calls to it:

```
runInMainThread([str] { display(std::move(str)); );
```

The `std::move` is just an optimization to avoid another copy of the string since you should not pass the string by reference in this case (it would be a dangling reference once the string object goes out of scope.)

This is not a high performance inter-thread communication mechanism. Every call will result in the construction of a temporary QObject and a temporary signal/slot connection. For periodic UI updates, it's good enough and it allows you to run any code in the main thread without having to manually set up signal/slot connections for the various UI update operations. But for thousands of UI calls per second, it's probably not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping this would work, but unfortunately am stuck having to use C++ 98

Comment: @esam430 Use functions or functors then instead of lambdas.

Comment: Exactly: lambdas are syntactic sugar for functors. Functors are simply classes that have `operator()`. So nothing too special. If you can write a lambda, you can write a functor :)

Comment: Yeah, I was more unsure of how to implement the wrapper function. But as I understand it, I could simply add that code to display()?
`void display(std::string output) 
{
MainWindow* gui = MainWindow::getMainWinPtr();
QObject tmp;
QObject::connect(&tmp, &QObject::destroyed, qApp, output.c_str(), Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Also, I get compile errors, saying that void QObject::destroyed(QObject*) is protected, as well as no matching function call for connect due to the qApp

Comment: @esam430 Hm. Are you on Qt 5? Or still using v4?

Comment: Using Qt 4 - gated by IT

Comment: @esam430 Well, no chance of being able to do this then. You need old-style `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` connections to member functions in the `slots:` section of a class for your various UI operations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: there's no way to make the `getMainWinPtr` method thread-safe, so this pseudo-singleton hack should probably go away. You can pass around some application-global context to all the objects that do application-global things like provide user feedback. Say, have a `MyApplication : QObject` (don't derive from `QApplication`, it's unnecessary). This can be passed around when new objects are created, and you'd then control the relative lifetime of the involved objects directly in the `main()` function:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow win;
  MyApplication foo;
  win.setApplication(&foo);
  // it is now guaranteed by the semantics of the language that 
  // the main window outlives `MyApplication`, and thus `MyApplication` is free to assume
  // that the window exists and it's OK to call its methods
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```

Of course `MyApplication` must take care that the worker threads are stopped before its destructor returns.

To communicate asynchronous changes to `QObject` living in (non-overloaded) `QThread`s (including the main thread), leverage the built-in inter-thread communication inherent in Qt's design: the events, and the slot calls that traverse thread boundaries.

So, given the `DisplayInGUI` method, you need a thread-safe way of invoking it:

```
std::string newOutput = ...;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWindow, [mainWindow, newOutput]{
  mainWindow->displayInGUI(newOutput);
});
```

This takes care of the thread-safety aspect. Now we have another problem: the main window can get hammered with those updates much faster than the screen refresh rate, so there's no point in the thread notifying the main window more often than some reasonable rate, it'll just waste resources.

This is best handled by making the `DisplayInGUI` method thread-safe, and leveraging the timing APIs in Qt:

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
  static constexpr m_updatePeriod = 1000/25; // in ms
  QMutex m_displayMutex;
  QBasicTimer m_displayRefreshTimer;
  std::string m_newDisplayText;
  bool m_pendingRefresh;
  ...

  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) override {
    if (event->timerId() == m_displayRefreshTimer.timerId()) {
      QMutexLocker lock(&m_displayMutex);
      std::string text = std::move(m_newDisplayText);
      m_pendingRefresh = false;
      lock.release();
      widget->setText(QString::fromStdString(text));
    }
    QWidget::timerEvent(event);
  }

  void DisplayInGUI(const std::string &str) {
    // Note pass-by-reference, not pass-by-value. Pass by value gives us no benefit here.
    QMutexLocker lock(&m_displayMutex);
    m_newDisplayText = str;
    if (m_pendingRefresh) return;
    m_pendingRefresh = true;
    lock.release();

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, &MainWindow::DisplayInGui_impl);
  }
private:
  Q_SLOT void DisplayInGui_impl() {
    if (!m_displayRefreshTimer.isActive()) 
      m_displayRefreshTimer.start(this, m_updatePeriod);
  }
};
```

In a more complex situation you'd likely want to factor out the cross-thread property setting to some "adjunct" class that would perform such operations without the boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks! I'm unclear by MyApplication : QObject and how it relates to the main window and related functionality.  Is there I should have the DisplayInGUI function should be? Also, I am stuck with using C++ 98 like a caveman

Comment: `MainWindow` should be user interface, nothing more, nothing less. Something like `MyApplication` should be the object that is shared across multiple modules. So, when you instantiate some of the "worker" objects, they get `MyApplication*` as an argument, and then can use that object to refer to application-wide data.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the fact that [`QTimer::singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-6) has an overload which, when called with a zero time interval, allows you to effectively schedule a task to be run on a specified thread during that thread's next idle slot...

```
void QTimer::singleShot(int msec, const QObject *context, Functor functor);
```

So your `MainWindow::mainFunction` could be something along the lines of...

```
void MainWindow::mainFunction ()
{
    ...
    std::string output = get_ouput_from_somewhere();
    QTimer::singleShot(0, QApplication::instance(),
                       [output]()
                       {
                           display(output);
                       });
    ...
}
```